# Selecting a Python Editing Tool

Tags: python, editors, ide

What do you recommend to use for Python editor/debugger tool on Linux?
I use python 3.6.0 and edit the files on Windows.
Now would like to do it in Linux environment
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ask ten people this question, and you will get twenty different answers.

Personally (for example), I use [`vim`](https://vim.org), but I can also see the merits of [Atom](https://atom.io).  If you're new to Python, there is also [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html).  [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org) is also a handy Python hacking tool.

But this is such a subjective question that there is no way anyone other than yourself will be able to determine which of the myriad tools available are the best for you in your specific use-case.